# Facebook window html encoding problem under MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-2

in the database I have this:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-11-23_1739.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-11-23_1739.png)

in my **View**, I output like:

```
defaultMsg: '<%: facebook.Social.PostWallDefaultMsg %>',
```

and **tried** like

```
defaultMsg: '<%: System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(facebook.Social.PostWallDefaultMsg) %>',
```

The **output in both codes** is:

```
defaultMsg: 'Tilmeld dig Citro&#235;ns Positive Power julekalender',
```

and in **Facebook window** I get:

[image]

**strangely enough** it decodes the correct output in all other parts/variables, but never in the message.

> **Is there any trick** that I can, either in MVC or through FB Javascript to get this correctly display?

Thank you.

test link: http://jul.citroen.dk/citroen/Subscriber/Register

---

**added**

I also tried changing the charset from `UTF-8` to `windows-1252` with no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried,

```
defaultMsg: '<%= facebook.Social.PostWallDefaultMsg %>'
```

When you do the following,

```
defaultMsg: '<%: System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(facebook.Social.PostWallDefaultMsg) %>',
```

You are encoding a decoded encode message (lol).

":" Encodes the output "=" doesnt

Comment: LOL... a guy get used to the `:` and knows nothing more :D Many thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @balexandre, Glad your sorted!